# Is there a way to get notified when an object expires?

Tags: c#, event-handling, observable, vsto, ms-project

I am struggling within a VSTO addin for MSProject to execute an action when the project is actually closed. I know there is a BeforeClose event, but that doesn't help because there is a Y/N/C dialog after that, that could stop the closing. Also, unlike Excel and Word, the ProjectClass does not provide a Close() event as suggested elsewhere.

My idea now was to store the open projects in an ObservableCollection and check at its ChangeEvent() which project was closed. But unfortunately the ChangeEvent is not called when the ProjectClass expires, because it has been closed and the reference is set to null.

I already thought of a custom ObservableCollection that checks for null references periodically via a timer, but that is very ugly in my opinion.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do but, would a destructor help?

Comment: There is this build in type in MS Project named ProjectClass with an iProject Interface. It exposes a BeforeClose() event. This event is fired when the user trys to close the document but its not the last event that occures on close. But I need to do something when the ProjectClass element actually died. It would be nice just to overwrite the destructor of that build-in class but I don't think it's that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [WindowActivate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.windowactivate(even)) event which should fire when a project is closed because another window would then become active. Keep track of which projects are open and then compare after each WindowActivate event to see if any of those are no longer open.

Comment: Thx, although there is only a WindowDeactivate I will considder that as possible solution, while still looking for a differnet solution. I was trying to create a dummy class derived from IDisposable and attaching one of its memberfunctions to an eventhandler of the project. The idea is that hook should keep the dummy class alive until the ProjectClass goes out of scope. But its seems not to be working like intended.